# Merge arrays in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, orm, rails-activerecord

How can I merge two arrays? Something like this:

```
@movie = Movie.first()
@options = Movie.order("RANDOM()").first(3).merge(@movie)
```

But it doesn't work.

In `@options` I need an array with four elements includes `@movie`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Like this?

```
⚡️ irb
2.2.2 :001 > [1,2,3] + [4,5,6]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But you don't have 2 arrays.

You could do something like:

```
@movie = Movie.first()
@options = Movie.order("RANDOM()").first(3).to_a << @movie
```

Comment: Rather [1, 2, 3] + [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Comment: Thanks! I always forget about "<<" :)

Answer (score 14):

To merge (make the union of) arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3].union([2, 4, 6]) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] (FROM RUBY 2.6)
[1, 2, 3] | [2, 4, 6] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

To concat arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3].concat([2, 4, 6]) #=> [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6] (FROM RUBY 2.6)
[1, 2, 3] + [2, 4, 6] #=> [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

To add element to an array:

```
[1, 2, 3] << 4 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But it seems that you don't have arrays, but active records. You could convert it to array with `to_a`, but you can also do directly:

```
Movie.order("RANDOM()").first(3) + [@movie]
```

which returns the array you want.

Answer (score 11):

There's two parts to this question:

1. How to "merge two arrays"? Just use the `+` method:

   ```
   [1,2,3] + [2,3,4]
   => [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
   ```
2. How to do what you want? (Which as it turns out, isn't merging two arrays.) Let's first break down that problem:

   `@movie` is an instance of your `Movie` model, which you can verify with `@movie.class.name`.

   `@options` is an `Array`, which you can verify with `@options.class.name`.

   All you need to know now is how to append a new item to an array (i.e., append your `@movie` item to your `@options` array)

   You do that using the double shovel:

   ```
   @options << @movie
   ```

   this is essentially the same as something like:

   ```
   [1,2,3] << 4
   => [1,2,3,4]
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Well, If you have an element to merge in an array you can use `<<`:

```
Eg: array = ["a", "b", "c"],  element = "d"
array << element 
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Or if you have two arrays and want duplicates then make use of `+=` or simply `+` based on your requirements on mutability requirements:

```
Eg: array_1 = [1, 2], array_2 = [2, 3]
array_1 += array_2
=> [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Or if you have two arrays and want to neglect duplicates then make use of `|=` or simply `|`:

```
Eg: array_1 = [1, 2], array_2 = [2, 3]
array_1 |= array_2
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

`@movie` isn't an array in your example, it is just a single instance of a movie. This should solve your problem:

```
@options << @movie
```