# How to merge two array objects in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I start with two arrays such as:

```
array1 = [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}]
array2 = [{"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]
```

How to merge this array into one array like this?

```
arraymerge = [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}, {"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]
```

Comment: `array1 + array2 #=> [{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}, {:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
array1 = [{ID:"1",name:"Dog"}]
array2 = [{ID:"2",name:"Cat"}]
p array1 + array2
# => [{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}, {:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}]
```

Or maybe this is superfluous:

```
array1 = [{ID:"1",name:"Dog"}]
array2 = [{ID:"2",name:"Cat"}]
array3 = [{ID:"3",name:"Duck"}]

p [array1, array2, array3].map(&:first)
# => [{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}, {:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}, {:ID=>"3", :name=>"Duck"}]
```

Comment: can we remove ":" ?

Comment: No @TijeKusnadi, that wouldn't work, that's they way to call `to_proc` on the object, is equivalent to write `.map{|e| e.first}`, you can choose what to use.

Answer (score 5):

Other answer for your question is to use [`Array#concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
array1 = [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}]
array2 = [{"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]

array1.concat(array2)
# [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}, {"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add them together:

```
puts array1+array2
{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}
{:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}
```

Or:

```
p array1+array2
[{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}, {:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}]
```

See also: [Merge arrays in Ruby/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978413/merge-arrays-in-ruby-rails)

Comment: arraymerge = [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}, {"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]

Comment: i want the array symbol still there , how do i do that?

Comment: It's still an array. `puts` prints it a little differently than `p` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `+` operator to do that

```
array1 = [{"ID":"1","name":"Dog"}]
array2 = [{"ID":"2","name":"Cat"}]

arraymerge = array1 + array2
#=> [{:ID=>"1", :name=>"Dog"}, {:ID=>"2", :name=>"Cat"}]
```